# how to remove on while looping count++ counter

Tags: php

hello i want to ask on display on my receipt. this is my receipt

```
|Food Name    |Price|
 Burger No : 1  
|Bun          |$1.00|
|Lamb         |$2.00|
|Pickel       |$1.20|
|Chilli       |$0.60|
 Burger No : 2
|Standard     |$0.80|
|Chicken      |$1.00|
|Normal       |$1.00|
|Normal       |$1.00|
 Burger No : 3
|Crispy       |$1.30|
|Beef         |$1.20|
|Extra        |$1.10|
|Hot          |$1.10|
 Burger No : 4
```

this is my coding

```
if($query_run = mysql_query($query1))
            {


                echo "

                <tr>
                <td>Food Name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                </tr>";

                $counter = 0;

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
                {

                    if($counter==0)
                     {
                     echo"<tr>
                        <td>Burger No:1</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }

                    echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                    <td>$".$row['total']."</td>
                    </tr>";

                    $total_price += $row['total'];
                    //echo "burger $counter";
                     $counter++;

                     if($counter==4)
                     {
                     echo"<tr>
                        <td>Burger No:2</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }

                     if($counter==8)
                     {
                     echo"<tr>
                        <td>Burger No:3</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }

                     if($counter==12)
                     {
                     echo"<tr>
                        <td>Burger No:4</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }


                }
```

my question is how can i remove the burger no example below:

if i buy 8 items then it should display burger no 1 and burger no 2 list...but the burger no 3 will also appear, same goes if i buy 12 items the burger no 4 will appear. How can i remove the burger no?

Please and thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: try placing `$counter++;` after this statment `if($counter==12)
                     {
                     echo"<tr>
                        <td>Burger No:4</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }
`

Comment: You really need to migrate your codebase over to using the mysqli_* extension or PDO. The mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 of PHP (the next version). Yours or any other site that uses the mysql_* extension will break instantly if the server is migrated over to php version 7. This article http://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/ will take you through how to convert your codebase over to using PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add condition like

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
{

  if($counter==0){
     echo"<tr>
       <td>Burger No:1</td>
      </tr>";
  }

                echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                <td>$".$row['total']."</td>
                </tr>";

                $total_price += $row['total'];
                //echo "burger $counter";
                 $counter++;

               if($counter < $num_rows) {
                 if($counter==4 )
                 {
                 echo"<tr>
                    <td>Burger No:2</td>
                    </tr>";
                 }

                 if($counter==8)
                 {
                 echo"<tr>
                    <td>Burger No:3</td>
                    </tr>";
                 }

                 if($counter==12)
                 {
                 echo"<tr>
                    <td>Burger No:4</td>
                    </tr>";
                 }
              }


            }
```